# How to Create NPM packages from a .vue file

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I have a `index.js`  file with:

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue';
module.exports = MyComponent;
```

I want to publish this as `npm package` so that i can use this component by `npm install my-component`

When i try to test by importing component from compiled js file got `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined`

But work fine when i import from `.vue` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add a `package.json` in the directory and in [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) field of `package.json` add primary entry point to your component.

You can have a look at this simple npm component: [vue-just-another-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-just-another-dropdown), which will give you more idea.

Comment: Whe i  import from compiled js file  got "[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined".

Comment: Can you post that whole code of this component and where you are using it, there may be some other error.

Comment: @mrabbani instead  of `module.exports = MyComponent;` try `export default MyComponent`

Comment: @mrabbani I have created a npm package: [vue-just-another-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-just-another-dropdown) You can check the working [example folder](https://github.com/mimani/vue-just-another-dropdown/tree/master/example). I am using it [here](https://github.com/mimani/vue-just-another-dropdown/blob/master/example/just-another-vue-app/src/components/Hello.vue#L18).

Comment: For multiple components, can I put a mixin importing all components?