# How to export ".vue" file as plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue-cli and create a input component with ".vue" file. How can i export this to install by npm command line.

Comment: You wouldn't.  You would compile your components and bundle them as a javascript bundle and import that bundle with a module loader such as browserify or webpack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create NPM packages from a .vue file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374223/how-to-create-npm-packages-from-a-vue-file)